# How to make firefox plugin compatible with FF 3.6.13

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, firebug, compatibility

Id like to install [this plugin for Firebug](http://code.google.com/p/firephp/downloads/detail?name=FirebugTestExtension-0.0.2.xpi&can=2&q=), but it says that its incompatible with FF 3.6.13. How to make it compatible(I have never done any FF development, so any pointers would be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the add-in [Nightly Tester Tools](http://www.oxymoronical.com/web/firefox/nightly). With it you can overwrite the state of incompatibility.

[Here](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/10/29/enable-firefox-incompatible-add-ons-and-this-add-on-is-for-older-versions-of-firefox/) it is explained how to use it.